# Question on sequences on banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am trying to do this exercise: Suppose $X$ is a Banach Space and $(x_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence in $X$. Suppose $f \in X^{*}$ with $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|f\left(x_{j}\right)\right|<\infty$. Prove that there is a constant $M>0$ such that $\sup _{k \in \mathrm{N}}\left\|\sum_{j=1}^{k} \epsilon_{j} x_{j}\right\|_{X} \leq M$ for any sequence $\left(\epsilon_{j}\right)_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\epsilon_{j}=\pm 1\right)$.

I tried to use the fact that
$$\sup _{k \in \mathrm{N}}\left\|\sum_{j=1}^{k} \epsilon_{j} x_{j}\right\|_{X} \leq \sup _{k \in \mathrm{N}}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left\| \epsilon_{j} x_{j}\right\|_{X} \leq \sup _{k \in \mathrm{N}}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left\|  x_{j}\right\|_{X},$$
together with defining $\hat{x}_n \in X^{**}$ such that $\hat{x}_n(f)=f(x_n)$ and somehow try to use the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) to connect both, but I am not sure how to do it, and I am a bit confussed on how to use it, because maybe I can define a sequence of operators using the partial sums or something similar. Can you give me please some hint. Thanks

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\forall f \in X^*$ we have $\sum_{j=1}^\infty |f(x_j)| < +\infty$? Because otherwise the sequence $(x_j)_j$ may be in $\ker f$.

Comment: @mechanodroid I guess, the statement is ambiguous about it, but I am assuming it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to show that the set $$S = \left\{\sum_{j=1}^k \varepsilon_jx_j : \varepsilon_j = \pm 1,k \in \Bbb{N}\right\}$$
is bounded. For any $f \in X^*$ we have
$$\left|f\left(\sum_{j=1}^k \varepsilon_jx_j\right)\right| \le \sum_{j=1}^k |\varepsilon_j f(x_j)| = \sum_{j=1}^k |f(x_j)| = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |f(x_j)| < +\infty$$
so $\{f(s) : s \in S\}$ is bounded by $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |f(x_j)|$ in the field. Since $f\in X^*$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $S$ is weakly bounded. The uniform boundedness principle now implies that $S$ is bounded.